# Recursively execute command in all directories using Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to execute the executable pngout file to compress all images contained in a folder and its subfolder. I'm using a Windows 7 machine.
I've tried with the following code:

```
for %i in (*.png) do pngout "%i" /kp
for /r /d %%x in (*) do (
    pushd "%%x"
    for %i in (*.png) do pngout "%i" /kp
    popd
)
```

However there is an issue as I get this error:
**i" /kp Unexpected**

However executing on a single line this command it works (on the current directory):

```
for %i in (*.png) do pngout "%i" /kp
```

Any pointers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in a batch file and change the `%i` terms to `%%i`