CWD contains files with same names as system headers
If the current directory contains a file with the same name as a system header, the compiler will first search the current directory even for includes from within system headers.
Is there a way to avoid that?
Simple reproduction case:
Working directory contains an empty limits.h and main.cpp with
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << INT_MAX << std::endl;
}

Running either g++ main.cpp or clang main.cpp causes an error saying that INT_MAX was not declared. With the limits.h absent, compilation works and the program works as expected. The <climits> system header on my system (ArchLinux updated at 21-04-2023) declares only LLONG limits and includes <limits.h> for the rest. However that seems to include my empty limits.h instead of the system one.
I ran into this issue in a more complex project when including <memory>, which included <limits.h> 6 files deep.

see also here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html for the list in which order gcc scans the include directories. THere are several places in the list where you can put a path

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736140/problems-with-header-having-the-same-name-but-different-case-as-a-standard-hea

Formally speaking, I think that this could be considered a bug in the compiler. Knowing how headers are organized, however, I can understand it (although it could easily be fixed by inserting a symlink to limits.h in the directory with the compiler headers). Having said that: creating header files with the same name as standard headers (or system headers) is just looking for trouble.
